# RAII and virtual destructors

Tags: c++

I created an abstract class and then created child classes that inherit this abstract class.

```
class A{
public:
     virtual A* clone() const = 0;
     virtual A* create() const = 0;
    ~virtual A(){};
    // etc.
private:
    A(){};
};
```

child classes

```
class B: public A{};
class C: public A{};
```

I can now populate a vector with these classes using a pointer of type A and access the child classes via polymorphism.

```
vector<A*> Pntr;
```

The problem is I want each child class to deal with its own memory release, kind of like RAII. However RAII doesn't work with virtual destructors. Is there a way I can do this?

Comment: FYI, constructors cannot be `virtual`, only methods and destructors can be.

Comment: [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) might be of help.

Comment: *"I want each child class to deal with its own memory release"* - What does that mean?

Comment: RAII simply doesnt work at all in any realworld scenario. It works only with PODs and not with OOP

Answer (score 10):

> However RAII doesn't work with virtual destructors.

Of course it does. The `virtual`-ness of the destructor doesn't matter. You just need to actually call it. When raw pointers go out of scope, they don't destroy the object they point to. That's what [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) is for:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> pointers;
```

When that vector goes out of scope, all of the `unique_ptr<A>`'s will get destroyed, which will `delete` all the underlying raw pointers they own, which will call the destructors of `B` or `C` (or ...) as appropriate and free all of the memory.

Side-note: `virtual A()` is wrong; you cannot have a virtual constructor.

Comment: Related: [Stroustrup:  Why don't we have virtual constructors?](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#virtual-ctor)